# Most elegant way to split a string and find its resulting ordered combinations

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am looking for the most elegant way to split up a string by a separator and find its possible combinations.

e.g:

`'foo.bar.baz'`

=>

`['foo', 'foo.bar', 'foo.bar.baz']`

I wouldn't mind using underscorejs either.

edit:

what I have tried so far

```
function comb(words) {                                                                                                                       
    var combinations = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {  
        var currentState = [];                                                                                                               
        for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {                                                                                                       
            currentState.push(words[j]);                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                                                    
        console.log('current state', currentState.join('.'));                                                                                
        combinations.push(currentState.join('.'));                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                        
    return combinations;                                                                                                                     
}                                                                                                                                            

console.log('combinations', comb('foo.bar.baz'.split('.')));
```

which outputs `combinations [ 'foo', 'foo.bar', 'foo.bar.baz' ]`

I am using this for an app with nested states. e.g: `home.users.list` has these states activated: `home`, `home.users`, `home.users.list`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? `.split()`? `.match()`? Is `bar.baz` not a valid combination in your example?

Comment: Also, what about `foo.baz`?

Comment: and ordered how? Alphabetically it would be bar.baz.foo...

Comment: updated my question with my current code and the 'ordered' thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what constitutes "most elegant", but here's a fairly compact solution that uses underscore:

```
function comb(words) {
    var accumulate = "";
    return _.map(words.split("."), function(word) {
        var t = accumulate + word;
        accumulate = t + ".";
        return t;
    });
 }
```

Differs slightly from your example, in that the argument to `comb` is the string you want to split.  Obviously, you could split before calling, as in your example, rather than doing it inside the function.

Comment: Same solution one liner: `'home.users.list'.split('.').reduce(function (res, word) {
    res.arr.push(res.s += word);
    res.s += '.';
    return res;
}, {arr: [], s: ''}).arr;`

Comment: @plalx Post it. To be fair, it isn't really a one liner since you have multiple statements on one line. But it is a clever use of an object as the initial value, and has the advantage of not taking a dependency on underscore js.

Answer (score 0):

```
function comb(words) {
    var combinations = [], temp = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        combinations.push(temp + words[i]);
        temp += words[i] + ".";
    }
    return combinations;
}

console.log('combinations', comb('foo.bar.baz'.split('.')));
```

**Output**

```
combinations [ 'foo', 'foo.bar', 'foo.bar.baz' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way:

```
function comb(str) {
    var index = -1, arr = [];
    while( (index = str.indexOf('.', index + 1) ) >= 0 ) {
        arr.push(str.substring(0, index));
    }
    arr.push(str);
    return arr;
}

console.log("combinations are: " + comb("foo.bar.baz"));
```